# How do I return each item in a JS array as separate html elements?

Tags: javascript, html

The array below is what I have and the html below that is what I am trying 
to return, any ideas how to achieve this?

```js
 function onChange(e) {
    var selected = this.select()[0],
        item = this.dataItem(selected);
    var info = [item.LeadID, item.Subject, item.Email, item.Phone];
    var moreInfo = info.join('<span>'+info+'</span>');
    document.getElementById("moreInfo").innerHTML =  moreInfo;
}
```

```html
    <div id="moreInfo">
      <span>211</span>
      <span>Re: Energy Transfer</span>
      <span>evelyn.adams@sampleemail.com</span>
      <span>0457767890</span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `map` method by passing a *callback* provided function as argument. The scope of using `map` is creating elements like `<span>elem</span>`

Then just use `join` method in order to create the string will be passed as value for *innerHTML* property of the `moreInfo` *DOM* element.

```js
var info = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var moreInfo = info.map(a=> '<span>'+a+'</span>').join('');
document.getElementById("moreInfo").innerHTML =  moreInfo;
console.log(document.getElementById("moreInfo").innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="moreInfo"></div>
```

Comment: Beautiful!! Thank you so very much @Mihai Alexandru-Ionut

Comment: @codeflower, you're welcome! Don't forget accept answer in order to help other people.

Comment: I havent forgotten just waiting for the timer to accept to finish lol, i've just tested it in my code and it works like a charm, so thanks again